# LOAD DATA INFILE bug in phpMyAdmin 3.5.7

Tags: phpmyadmin

I found a rather nasty bug in phpMyAdmin using the LOAD DATA INFILE that is beyond frustrating.
Basically the path I am specifying is being changed by the program
the following command:
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\CaliberMap.csv'
has a bug which insists the path is:
'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\CaliberMap.csv'
completely ignoring the path I specified (or, rather butchering it!).
giving me the following error:

## 29 - File 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\CaliberMap.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

I'm stumped as it is impossible to import anything to my tables.

Any ideas? Bug patches? I've spent hours of hair pulling with no answers on the Internet.

Comment: I've tried the import function as well, unfortunately, MS EXCEL cannot export a CSV correctly - so that's out. Tried manually adding quotes, but then the row delimiters are not accepted (no matter what I put in) - even "auto" which does not work either. Tried the ODS format as well.  MyPHPAdmin is a horrendously poor tool for Windows machines - it just does not work!!!

Answer (score 1):

try to use "LOCAL" keyword"

"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\CaliberMap.csv'"

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for this. Note that on Windows, I had to replace backward slashes with forwards.